# Fast way to get to perform a request from multiple hasMany association

Tags: grails

What is the fast and best way to perform a request from multiple 'hasMany' association  ?

Here's a simple code that I have.

From the instance of A I want to get all instances of B domain (a list of id) where login == "toto"?

```
class A {

   static hasMany =  [BList:B]

}


class B {

   static hasMany =  [CList:C]

}


class C {

   static hasMany =  [DList:D]

}


class D {

       String login
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with an `HQL`:

```
String query = """
 from a.bList 
where a = :a 
  and exists (select 1
                from C c
                   , D d
               where d.c = c
                 and c.b in a.bList
                 and d.login = :login)
"""
def result = A.executeQuery(query, [a: aInstance, login: "login"])
```

More information about executeQuery [in the docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html).

Comment: Thanks for your response. When I executed this query I had an exception:
"could not resolve property: a of: ...."

Comment: @Jils you don't have the `belongsTo` in B?

Comment: an other issue was occurred: 
"Message: a.bList is not mapped [
    from a.bList..." 
I tried to fixed the issue regarding this topic:
http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Error-using-DomainClass-executeQuery-quot-DomainClass-is-not-mapped-quot-td1366153.html

without success.